# If condition true, but code is not executed in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

I have a script which triggers a movement when a rotation is completed. The script casts the Euler angle of a transform to an `int`. If it is `true`, the condition is executed. For some weird reason, the code in the `if` condition does not execute, even if the condition is `true`. I have confirmed the condition is `true` through both my compiler and the debug log.

---

Here is my code:

```
if(rotationInitiate)
{
    transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(transform.eulerAngles, 
        new Vector3(0, 0, angleOfRotation), Time.deltaTime * speedOfRotation);

    Debug.Log(transform.eulerAngles.z);

    if((int)transform.eulerAngles.z == 180)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hurray we have successfully executed the if statement");

        // More rotation stuff
    }
}
```

As you can see by my log, the angle returns an exact value of 180, but does not enter the `if` statement to perform the second log output:

[image: The console prints a <code>z</code> angle of 180 degrees, but does not print the statement in the <code>if</code> statement that directly follows.]

---

Why might my `if` statement not be executing?

Comment: Try removing that int cast

Comment: What if you try a more robust condition like `Mathf.Abs(transform.eulerAngles.z -180.f) < 1.0f`? Also make sure the debug output is something unique so that it is not mistaken for some other, forgotten somewhere else, debug output.

Comment: The `angleOfRotation` is 180 and the `speedOfRotation` is 10.

Comment: Thanks Wondra ,your solution seems to have worked. I replaced my if condition with the one provided by you and it worked. Though it still bothers me why my original solution wouldn't work. Thanks for your help too Gnemlock

Comment: The thing is, I copied your code into *my* ide, and it *also* worked =/ I assumed you were giving a really small value or something. That said, if your moving at 10 * Time.deltaTime, Your `Update` method must only be beig called approx. *10 or less times per second*, as that is the only situation where you could pass a value of 1 or greater into the `Slerp()` method. *In turn, this is the only way you could immediately reach the rotation of 180, unless you already were at the rotation of 180*.

Comment: Note that Slerp moves *incrementally*, not *straight away*. We give it a value between 0 and 1, pointing to the increment we want. 0 means the start position, 1 means the end position, 0.5 means the middle.

Comment: I did not exactly get what you were trying to say in the last two comments Gnemlock. Could you explain in a bit more detail ?

Comment: @Ikun this goes a bit off-topic, but [you can read more about patterns for using Lerp in this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/113373/39518).

Comment: Change {Debug.Log(transform.eulerAngles.z);} to {Debug.Log((int)transform.eulerAngles.z);} and let's see what's the output in the console. Probably nothing exceptional will appear there, but as everyone are having a hard time with this, let's try something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Debug.Log(transform.eulerAngles.z);` printing `180` does not mean that `z` has the value `180`. It means it has a floating point value very close to `180`, but that could be for instance `179.999969482421875`.

This means that the `if((int)transform.eulerAngles.z == 180)` test will not work, because casting `179.999969482421875` to `int` yields `179`, not `180`.

A possible solution is to round the value: `if (Math.Round(transform.eulerAngles.z) == 180.0)`.

Comment: I agree, but in an initial screenshot I had uploaded, I had shown that the `if` condition was indicated `true` by the debugger in mono( the one which appears on hovering over the `==` sign). Doesn't this mean that the condition had evaluated to true ?

Comment: The condition has not evaluated to true, since the code inside was not executed. There may be a problem in the debugger visualiser, but you should first fix your code.

Comment: Interesting, I will try this out.

Comment: This seems to explain why the code *wont* work. It *does* work, when I try it given the reported values.

Comment: @Gnemlock it may sometimes work, but that’s only by chance; the outcome will highly depend on the value of `DeltaTime`.

Answer (score 1):

I copy pasted your code into a coroutine:

```
private IEnumerator TestCoroutine()
{
    GameObject newGameObject = new GameObject();

    while (true)
    {
        newGameObject.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(
            newGameObject.transform.eulerAngles, 
            new Vector3(0, 0, 180), Time.deltaTime * 10);

        Debug.Log(newGameObject.transform.eulerAngles.z);

        if ((int)newGameObject.transform.eulerAngles.z == 180)
        {
            Debug.Log("Hurray we have successfully executed the if statement");
        }

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

I ran it, and it worked:

[image: It works when I try it in a Coroutine.]

Comment: It's Unity Version 5.4.1f1 personal edition

Comment: @Ikun, you say that this solution worked. Could you please confirm by confirming the answer?

Comment: Why is this accepted if the code is still obviously wrong?

Comment: I had originally accepted this answer, as it had shown that my code was right but the problem seems to be with my environment. But then I realized that even Sam's answer is right and kind of more detailed about the possible causes, to the problem. So I have decided to accept that answer. That being said I have upvoted this answer as well so it might be helpful to some people. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a slerp and casting to int, your rotation doesn't actually ever hit 180, since casting cuts off anything after the comma (179.999999999999.. => 179). The Debug.Log rounds instead, so if you want the behavior to be the same try Mathf.Round instead of the int cast.

It is better to use the solution Wondra posted in the comment above though, this is just to make it clear why it broke before.

Comment: It does. And the user demonstrated that the if statement is false `if((int)transform.eulerAngles.z == 180) ` , as it didn't write out the `Debug.Log("Hurray we have successfully executed the if statement"); ` but only the rounded `Debug.Log(transform.eulerAngles.z);`

Comment: Huh, very strange indeed. :) Oh wait, the slerp t value doesn't seen to be advanced from step to step, wouldn't this mean that it would not "move" but rather shake around the value of Time.deltaTime?

Comment: It *should*, it is clear the original asker did not initially understand how `Lerp` and `Slerp` work. It also appears *strange* that they would have the reported issues, regardless. I have confirmed that the code works, on my side, and another user reports something similar.